# Regex for Date between 19000101 to 20001231

Tags: c#

can any body suggest REGX for below date range

Format is CCYYMMDD
19000101 to 20001231
Blank

I am new to the REGX,please help me Out.

Comment: What does the word Blank mean?

Comment: I fully concur with the other answers here, but for your edification, a fairly complete regex for your specification would be `(?<year>19\d\d|2000)(?<month>0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?<day>0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])`.  Of course this doesn't account for which months are 28, 29, or 30 days, as that is beyond the scope of regex.

Answer (score 5):

Regex to parse datetimes??? A wise man once said:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think:
>
> *I know, I'll use regular expressions.*
>
> Now they have two problems.

Come on, you have built-in methods for such tasks like [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
string dateStr = "19000101";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date)
{
    // you could safely use the date instance created for you here
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidFormatException("Sorry the date you have given me is not in the expected format");
}
```

Alright, now that you have used the aforementioned method to parse the date, you could trivially easy test whether this date falls within the expected range:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2000, 12, 31);
DateTime date = ... use the previous method to parse your string
if (date > start && date < end)
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // the date is outside the range
}
```

Comment: thanks but here you are hard coding the dates.for future if we need change then we need to change the c# code.I need REGX as it is used in our schema

Comment: What do you mean by *schema*? What prevents you from using the same technique as I showed in order to read the `start` and `end` values dynamically from your *schema* (whatever this *schema* means)? This way you won't be hardcoding anything. So no, believe, oh please believe me, you **DO NOT NEED A REGEX**.